# Angular: data sending from form (with raw / json options)

Tags: angular

From my Angular 6 form I should send some data with the same configuration which I have in Postman (I send a screenshot with the complete configuration: as you can see, I chose the options but raw / Json).

[image]

I tried the following example but it doesn't work because I receive a "bad request 400" error message. This is my code which doesn't work:

```
public login() {

        let userPassword = this.registrationForm.get('password').value;
        let userLogin = this.registrationForm.get('email').value;
        let userLangKey = 'en';

        /*
        const transferObject = {

            password: userPassword,
            login: userLogin,
            langKey: userLangKey
        }

        JSON.stringify(transferObject);
        */

        const req = this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/register/', {
            password: userPassword,
            login: userLogin,
            langkey: userLangKey
        })
        .subscribe(
            res => {
            console.log(res);
        },
            err => {
            console.log("Error occured");
        }

      );
    }
```

I also tried to edit my code in this way but I receive the same error:

```
(...)

const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
              'Content-Type':  'application/json'
            })
        }; 

        const req = this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/register/', {
            password: userPassword,
            login: userLogin,
            langkey: userLangKey
            }, httpOptions)

        .subscribe(
            res => {
            console.log(res);
            },
            err => {
            console.log("Error occured");
            }

(...)
```

Comment: You could read the form values and create an object yourself, then just call `JSON.stringify` on that object and send it as you send any other data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the absolutely quick response! Can you sent a little example, only i.e. whit one single data as an username? PS Make response as main question response and not here, so I can flag you as definitive solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried myself and solved the problem; considering my last code version I posted here, all was correct and the once problem was simply activate. In the previous http row, I only define this.(blablabla); it was enough at the end of this row ".subscribe(blablabla)" to activate the function. Only this command; nothing else. Thank; I copy below my correct code. I hope, it can be useful for someone else.

```
public login() {

        let userPassword = this.registrationForm.get('password').value;
        let userLogin = this.registrationForm.get('email').value;
        let userLangKey = 'en';

        const transferObject = {

            password: userPassword,
            login: userLogin,
            langKey: userLangKey
        }

        let header:HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        const object = JSON.stringify(transferObject);
        const self = this;  

                //Here is the point!
        return self.httpClient.post(PathService.authPath()+'register', object, {headers: header}).subscribe((response: Response) => {

            this.helperService.snackBarWarning('all works correctly');
        });
    }
```

Comment: `'Content-Type', 'application/json'` and `JSON.stringify(dataToBeSent)` is enough

Answer (score 3):

Please use third parameter to set headers for this post request.

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })
};    
this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
```

Comment: I edited my main question with the application of your solution to my problem but I receive the same error; have I written something wrong? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure how your form is built up so for this example I'm assuming you're using ngModel or you have already extracted the needed values from your form.

```
let l = 'test';
let p = 'pass';
let lk = 'en'

const transferObject = {
  login: l,
  password: p,
  langKey: lk
}

const object JSON.stringify(transferObject);

// requires injecting HttpClient in constructor
this.http.post<object>('http://myurl.com', string);
```

Then on the receiving end you can reverse this action to get your object back like so:

```
let string = // receive your string
const receivedObject = JSON.parse(string)
```

You can read more about the Javascript/Typescript JSON functions here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp

Comment: Thank you! I have already retrieve my form data and convert with JSON.stringify; the problem is also not what happens after this operation because I should sent to a backend already developed and efficient. My only question is: how can I send this info to this backend? As you can see in attach "postman" configuration screenshot, all works correctly if in my "post" method to the link "localhost:8080/something..." I choose not "form" mode but "raw". Could you please sent me a row of example valid to send this info by post to this link but with "raw" option?

Comment: Thanks but it is referred to a database maybe, I don't see the way to insert my link and the JSON.stringify which you indicated me before... This is the only piece which is not yet present in my "mosaic"! Thank you very much.